# Надо, чтобы скрипт обработал js без перехода на другую страницу

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте, я не знаю как сделать php обработчик в js.

Т.е. Мне надо, чтоб этот php скрипт обработал js без перехода на другую страницу.

```
<table width="726" cellspacing="4" align="left">
  <tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td width="80" rowspan="3"><img src="<?php echo $friends[avatarUser]; ?>" width="80" height="80"></td>
    <td width="185"><?php echo $friends[nameUser]; ?> <?php echo $friends[surnameUser]; ?></td>
    <td width="207" rowspan="2">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $friens[id]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submitFriendOk" value="Добавить">
    </form>
    </td>
    <td width="224" rowspan="2"><form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $friens[id]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submitFriendNo" value="Отказать">
    </form></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td height="21"><?php echo $friends[cityUser]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td height="21" colspan="3"><?php echo $friends[statusUser]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

А точнее кнопки "Добавить" и "Отказать". Я не знаю, в js вообще обрабатываются формы или нет. Так что напишите пожалуйста полный скрипт.

На кнопку "Добавить" в php у меня такой скрипт.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$friendOk = mysql_query("UPDATE `friend` SET `status` = `status` - '0' WHERE `id` = '$id'") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());;
```

На кнопку "Отказать":

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$friendNo = mysql_query("UPDATE `friend` SET `status` = `status` - '3' WHERE `id` = '$id'") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());;
```

Comment: "А точнее кнопки "Добавить" и "Отказать". Я не знаю, в js вообще обрабатываются формы или нет. Так что напишите пожалуйста полный скрипт."
Никто за вас писать не будет. Либо за деньги, либо учите js.

Comment: И я вас люблю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем тут js вообще? Вы можете разместить 2 `<button>` указать разный экшн им, и обрататывать сколько пожелаете. или же в этом случае можете проверять `isset($_POST['submitFriendNo'])` или `isset($_POST['submitFriendOk'])`

Comment: У меня одна проблема из-за чего я и хочу сделать на js. Когда я вставляю много php скриптов, то на странице перестает отображаться все что под скриптом.

Comment: значит надо искать в чем причина, возможно где то забыли запятую или кавычку, пробовать урощать скрипты и размещать. Они не должны делать так, что перестает что то отображаться под скриптом. Проблема где то в коде

Comment: Искал, все правильно.